# Adding LOG.i() to the program

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using the "Sams teach yourselfh Android Application Develoment in 24 hours" Book.

Got this program

```
package com.androidbook.droid1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author Trashcan
 *
 */
public class Droid1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        private static final String TAG = "app_name";

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(TAG,"WTF is going on ?");
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html is the API of it.

Been trying and dorking around with it and just haven't gotten to any idea where Eclipse will accept it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't define a `static` variable within a method.  Refactor your code so that the declaration of `TAG` is at the class level.  For example:

```
package com.androidbook.droid1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author Trashcan
 *
 */
public class Droid1Activity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "app_name";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(TAG,"WTF is going on ?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked, moved the String a few lines longer up and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Although, you understand that it wasn't necessarily moving it up that caused the change, it was moving it out of the method.

Answer (score 3):

There is a line there that shouldn't be in the method but outside of the method. Don't you get a warning saying as much?

Comment: yep, i forgot thatone. 

Illegal modifier for parameter TAG; only final is permitted Droid1Activity.java /Hour 1 - Droid1/src/com/androidbook/droid1 line 16 Java Problem

Comment: Exactly, and what does that tell you about line 16 (hint: you can't specify visibility and static for a local variable)? That line doesn't belong in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` first in `onCreate()`. I'm not sure if this will fix anything, but I can't really tell what your problem is.

Also, it would seem more appropriate to use `Log.wtf()` in this particular case, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: Haha... I didn't know Android had a Log.wtf()

Comment: New to this, so I'm gonna test out more things also. This is mainly for working on the Eclipse Debugger, as know already. Thanks for the reply.